# Delete button not deleting all values from database

Tags: php, mysql

I created a delete button on my detail page which deletes the values which must be deleted how ever.... After deleting it's seems like the code is working because it doens't show any information on the detailpage but when I go to PHPMyAdmin it's still showing some values... I am using three tables person, address, cv after pressing delete the values from person is deleted but not from address and cv.

My delete code:

```
<?php
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "usbw";
      $dbname = "persons";

// Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }

      $id=$_GET['id']; 

      $stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM person WHERE person_id = ?'); 
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);                                         

      $result = $stmt->execute();    
      if ($result === FALSE) {
        die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
      }
      $conn->close();
?>
```

I have ON DELETE set up on CASCADE for both address_id and cv_id which has a relation with person_cv and person_address. Also I do not want to start a new topic for this small question... When I press delete it is going to a empty page called http://localhost:8080/Website/delete.php?id=(randomid) I want it to go back to the detailpage.

Comment: just to be sure I changed the '$id=$_GET['id'];' to '$id=$_GET['person_id'];' because it's called person_id in my database but after testing it still only deletes all person information from table person and not from address and cv

Answer (score 0):

header("Location: http://localhost:8080/Website/detailpage");

(or whatever your detail page is called)

Answer (score 0):

check foreignKey Cascade

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "usbw";
    $dbname = "persons";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $id=$_GET['id']; 

    if ($conn->query(sprintf ( "DELETE FROM person WHERE person_id = '%s' ", mysql_real_escape_string ( $id ) ) )) {
        header('Location: detailpage.php'); 
    }
    else{
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        exit();
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```